# extract debug data value directly in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I recently moved to Visual Studio 2015, and while debugging, i see that i can no longer look at values directly unless I go past several levels of watch varaible like below

[image]

What I want is ***reference1Sm.data*** value displayed directly in watch window. is there setting i need to change or a hack to do so?

Thanks
sedy

Comment: are you sure that you were able to see that directly in previous versions of VS?

Comment: yes, i did not see "vbitbase","vbitdatabase" etc.

Comment: what VS was that? 2013?